# Website not displaying images or loading external CSS,JS

Tags: html, validation, hyperlink, live, broken-image

A website for a school that I built went live last week, and although it looks fine locally, online it's terrible.

Here is the link to it: http://www.centennial-s.schools.nsw.edu.au/

The problems I have identified are:

1. No images are displayed.
2. The CSS files are not loaded.
3. The JS files are not loaded.
4. None of the internal links work (external links are fine).

In fact anytime the index.html links to something within itself, it doesn't work. I can't even get off index.html to test the other pages.

I have spoken with the Department of Education IT Support and they bluntly told me that the code was not valid and that I should validate it. I have as much as possible and the only errors I am getting now are:

```
"Element text not allowed as child of element a in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)"
```

regarding some text-links in the footer.

I am not sure how to fix this error. But could someone tell me if this is enough to utterly break every link on the page?

If so, how do I make this valid?
And how do I get the page working live?

feel free to validate the site yourselves: http://validator.w3.org/

Thanks in advance,

Sam

Comment: Are you using a `.htaccess`? If you try to open an image, you'll see that the URI is "ignored" and it always prints the index.html

Comment: are you using some kind of url rewrite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a validation issue; the links should work and the CSS should load even if the HTML doesn't validate (even if the CSS ends up not working properly).

You're on to something when you said:

> In fact anytime the index.html links to something within itself, it doesn't work. I can't even get off index.html to test the other pages.

Find out why individual pages don't load.  You should be able to navigate through the links and load individual pages with the absolute URLs.  for instance, try to get http://www.centennial-s.schools.nsw.edu.au/css/indexStyle.css - you should get CSS, not the index page.

Look for some kind of rewriting or error handling that might be causing the server to serve up the wrong files.

Update: I did some more poking around and confirmed that regardless of which file you request, the server is always sending back the default HTML page.  definitely check on the items I mentioned above and confirm that you can actually load the CSS, JS, images, etc.  It's probably not your code or the validation of that code, but rather a server issue.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, I'll get in touch with the server guys again and ask them to check their work.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I linked the server guys to this page and they had a read over it and it seems to now be working. I'm glad it wasn't my fault, vindication feels nice.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just trying to get this to validate then remove the `<text>` tags. I looked in the list of elements for HTML4 and HTML5 and found no `text` element.  Some small errors like this can cause multiple validation errors.

The text element is causing 12 validation errors.

HTML4 Elements:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/index/elements.html

HTML5 Elements:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/elements.html

Comment: Thanks for the input, I don't know where I got the idea that a <text> element existed, I'm self taught so there are a few things I haven't picked up on yet.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a rewrite problem as every URL opens the same page. It's definitely not an HTML validation problem. The server reports itself as being IIS 7.5...since it sounds like you don't have access to it yourself, you should tell the IT support person in charge that the server is misconfigured.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.centennial-s.schools.nsw.edu.au/SpryAssets/SpryCollapsiblePanel.css does not exist.
http://www.centennial-s.schools.nsw.edu.au/images/buttons/contactButton.png does not exist.

Is that a 404 response that causes the redirection or do you you have a permanent redirection for everything to return to your home page.

Comment: That could be it, there is a redirect in place from the old website, to this new website. I didn't do the redirect myself, but I'll call the guy who did and ask him to check it.